# Qt5 QML module is not installed

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I'm confused about modules in Qt QML. I've read all the docs, but it doesn't make clear some basic ideas.

I understand that i can put a bunch of QML files into a directory and add a qmldir file to describe an identified module. When i do this and adjust the QML_IMPORT_PATH, QtCreator is happy and stops underlining the import ModuleName 1.0 line.

So creator is happy, but it does not work. I get module  is not installed.
my questions are:

- what does it mean by "installed". I have directory of files, but i haven't "installed" them anywhere.
- should i be building/compiling the module to make a DLL/.so ?
- does the module QML files go into the resources of the main app, otherwise where are they to be found?
- my main.qml file is part of the app resources, how does the app locate the resources of the module at runtime.

Sorry, for all these questions, but the basics of these modules is just not clear. I don't understand if a "module" is just the sharing of files or is it a compiled unit.

thanks for any help.

Comment: For me, the "module ... is not installed" error was entirely fixed by one sub-topic of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49326965/10278 -- I forgot the `<file>` entry for `qmldir` inside the `qrc` file.

Answer (score 24):

I'll try to answer your questions:

- I think *installed* means they are located in the proper paths, so
  that they can be found at runtime
- You should not necessarily create/build a `QmlExtensionPlugin` for that purpose. You can also use as a module plain QML files in one
  directory with a `qmldir` describing this module. It is a matter of
  distributing your code. With `QmlExtensionPlugin` you provide the
  module compiled, if you want to hide the code.
- The modules can be in resources system or as files on disk, it is up to you.
- The app looks for modules in predefined paths - in your app's directory, in Qt plugins path, in `QML2_IMPORT_PATH`, in directories that you added using `engine->addImportPath()`

There are a bunch of things that can lead to a module not being loaded. You can check the following:

1. Module identifier in `qmldir` should be the same as the directory
   name, where the module actually resides. For example **if your module
   has module identifier `module Test.Module` in `qmldir`, your module's
   relative path must be `Test/Module`**.
2. If it is a QML extension
   plugin (shared library), make sure that plugin's directory name is
   the same as plugin's name.
3. export `QML2_IMPORT_PATH` (make sure there is `2` in the name) env variable to point to directory containing your module. There is also a `QQmlEngine::addImportPath` method, which adds the directory to the list to lookup for plugins.
4. If it is a qml extension plugin (shared library), then there might be missing dependencies for it. You can check it by [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on Windows or `ldd` command on Linux.
5. Setting `QT_PLUGIN_PATH` runtime variable may help to load plugins. It should point to a directory containing you plugin's directory, not the plugin's directory itself.
6. You can also enable traces to see what's going on while plugins are loaded for better understanding of the problem - export `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` and `QML_IMPORT_TRACE=1` environment variables

You can also read this link:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-identifiedmodules.html

Comment: Thanks for explaining, but I'm still mostly in the dark. I've figured out that if i set `addImportPath` to an *absolute* path, it works. But i want the QML referenced to be local to the project. relative paths fail because they don't work from the resultant build directory.

I've also figured out how to compile the module + its resources to a DLL. But i've no idea how to load this DLL. arranging it to be in the import path doesn't work because, i think the DLL needs a qmldir. The DLL will register the types inside it, but that would involve loading it first. sort of chicken & egg??

Comment: Just provide the qmldir for the DLL plugin,  it is about 3 lines long, put qmldir next to your plugin, put this all in a folder with the proper name, as I stated in the answer, and put the folder next to an executable. This should work. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thank you.  After a long road and much searching, this helps a lot!

Comment: "Module identifier in qmldir should be the same as the directory name" This was the issue for me.

Answer (score 13):

In my case (I have all QML files in qrc resources) worked to add qmldir to resources also and call method addImportPath("qrc:/") of QQmlApplicationEngine.

My main.cpp looks like:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.addImportPath("qrc:/");
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
```

Important parts of my .pro file looks like:

```
RESOURCES += qml.qrc \
    MyModule/mymodule.qrc

QML_IMPORT_PATH += $$PWD
```

My qmldir:

```
module MyModule

MyItem          2.0 MyItem20.qml
MyItem          2.1 MyItem21.qml
```

My qrc:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/MyModule">
        <file>MyItem20.qml</file>
        <file>MyItem21.qml</file>
        <file>qmldir</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

And finally my main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

import MyModule 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    MyItem {
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

QtCreator is happy (not underlining components and imports) and module is loaded.
Hope this helps.

Comment: <qresource prefix="/MyModule"> i think this part is most important!

Answer (score 5):

I want to expand on [arxarian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46096179/1664052) - which I think is the best technique for integrating modules - but couldn't fit those thoughts in a comment, so here's a new answer.

It's important to first understand that qml modules and their associated resources are runtime entities and are assumed to separately exist at some location relative to the executable unless they're included in the application resources. By including them in the resources, they are still runtime entities, but they exist under the qrc:/ root path within the application binary. This hiding of the modules is the primary reason why I think this is the best technique, unless you want your modules to be open to revision after deployment, or to be independently deployable as precompiled plugins (i.e., in the resource storage of a dynamically linked library).

So here's my explanation of the important elements of [arxarian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46096179/1664052):

1. `engine.addImportPath("qrc:/");` is needed in the C++ code prior to loading the qml to instruct the engine to look for qml modules in the application resource storage.
2. `RESOURCES += MyModule/mymodule.qrc` is needed in the project (.pro) file to add the module's files to the [application resource storage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html).
3. `QML_IMPORT_PATH += $$PWD` in the project file tells *Qt Creator* to look for the module starting from the root of the project source tree. In my case I had to set this to a subdirectory (e.g., "ui/modules") because my module directories started there. The import path should include the root(s) beneath all module directories. As far as I can tell, this instruction is only for the Qt Creator IDE and does not impact the build - that's why #1 is needed.
4. The contents of the qmldir file is as is [standard for all qml modules](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html), but it's inclusion in the module's .qrc resource file is not intuitive until you think about what's happening with runtime storage. It needs to be in the .qrc so that it is included in the application resource storage, so that the engine can find it at runtime to define the module. `<qresource prefix="/MyModule">` in the module's .qrc file defines the module subdirectory relative to the qrc:/ root in the application resource storage.
5. The `import MyModule <version>` statement in qml is now setup for success. On startup the engine will have located the module in its directory under qrc:/, parsed the qmldir file there to define the module and established the name and version from those entries.

Hopefully this helps others understand what's going on, and please let me know if I've misunderstood anything.

Comment: your remark that  "qmldir file's inclusion in the module's .qrc resource file is not intuitive" led me to my mistake! I've been debugging "module xyz is not installed" for way too long, and that was my silly mistake: i forgot to list the `qmldir` file in my `qrc`. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue cost me a bit of time so I just post it here to perhaps save the next guy some effort.

My problem was that an invisible character had sneaked into the module name. Probably through copy and paste. Here my issue:

Example error output:

```
MyEngine failed to load component
qrc:/qml/main.qml:53 Type MyComponent unavailable
file:///Users/<pathToProject>/MyProject/qml/MyModule/MyComponent.qml:-1 No such file or directory
```

It all looks fine and the path displayed is indeed the correct one. So what is wrong?

Now, copy that path to a Terminal window:

```
file:///Users/<pathToProject>/MyProject/qml/MyModule/<feff>MyComponent.qml
```

There it is, the:

```
"<feff>"
```

Solved the issue by manually retyping the component name in the qmldir file, and thus effectively deleting the invisible character.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and have now fixed it. I found a QML plugin for iOS. There are several things that need to be taken care of:

**1. The plugin pro file needs an addition:**

> uri = IosTestPulgin

```
# this for error:
# static plugin for module “QtQuick” with name “IosTestPulgin” 
# has no metadata URI
QMAKE_MOC_OPTIONS += -Muri=$$uri

# thanks from:https://github.com/wang-bin/QtAV/issues/368
```

**2. The QML plugin qmldir file needs an additional line like this:**

```
classname IosqmlpluginPlugin
# for ERROR: Plugin iostestqmlplugin is missing a classname entry,
# please add one to the qmldir file.
# look for qt document http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html
```

**3 The client project pro file needs an addition like this:**

```
ios {
    IOSTestPlugin_BUNDLE.files += $$files($$[QT_INSTALL_QML]/IosTestPulgin/qmldir)
    IOSTestPlugin_BUNDLE.path =  IosTestPulgin
    QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA += IOSTestPlugin_BUNDLE
}
# for ios error: module is not installed
# this means external qml static plugin must add the plugin dir by manual
# in the app root dir
```