# QML error: qrc:/Main.qml:24 module "system" is not installed

Tags: c++, qt, scripting, qml, qqmlcomponent

I am new in QML and I have a project.
In one of my directories I have `/imports/system/qmldir` file where I have he following code:

```
singleton System 1.0 System.qml
App 1.0 App.qml
```

and in my source file I have

```
import system 1.0
```

And the error says that module system is not installed.

```
qrc:/Main.qml:24 module "system" is not installed
```

Could you please tell me the steps or flow of installing the module.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352930/qt5-qml-module-is-not-installed. Also can you post the exact error message?

Comment: qrc:/Main.qml:24 module "system" is not installed

Comment: See https://forum.qt.io/topic/50037/qml-included-modules-not-installed-unless-qml-directory-is-a-subdirectory-of-the-project-file/3. In it they say *"You need to set QML_ROOT_PATH in your .pro file to the path to the directory with your QML files. The default value is your project directory, that's why it works when you put your qml's right there."* Is Main.qml in your project root, or in a subdir?

Comment: my Main.qml is in project root, on the same level as .pro file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must call [`QQmlEngine::addImportPath()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#addImportPath) and pass the path to `/imports`.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.addImportPath("/path/to/imports"); // <==
    engine.load(...);

    return app.exec();
}
```